# Hash location strategy in angular4 app

Tags: angular, angular-router

I started working on angular4 app and I am using `hash location strategy` in that app. I am able to introduce `hash location strategy` and its working completely fine.

My question is: there is any way to adjust the position of `hash` in the url?

For example: My routing module is:

```
[
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'parent', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'parent',
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'upload', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'upload', component: UploaderComponent },
      {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
    ]
  }
]
```

And I am registering these routes as:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true });
```

When I loads my app, url comes out as:

```
http://localhost:4200/#/parent/upload
```

But, is there any way to make my route as:

```
http://localhost:4200/parent/#/upload
```

I was looking into the official doc for [angular-routing](https://angular.io/guide/router#browser-url-styles), but was not able to find out any way to achieve this.

Any useful suggestion to achieve this will be appreciated!!

Thanks!

Comment: You can change the base href inside the index.html from src/ folder. Default is <base href="/">, change to <base href="/parent/"> so your app will run under 'parent/' context

Comment: @ChristianBenseler: Thanks for quick reply. But that doesn't help me. Changing to <base href="/parent/"> didn't help me. App stopped working as app was trying to look each bundle file in "/parent" rather than "/", which is making files unavailable. Can you tell why this is happening?

Comment: why do you need that?

Comment: @ChristianBenseler: FYI: I changed <base href="/"> to <base href="/parent"> and it is working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@ChristianBenseler's comment helped me to get to this solution:

In my `Index.html` file, I change the base href as:

```
<base href="/"> to <base href="/parent">
```

and in my routing module, it is changed as:

```
[
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'upload', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'upload', component: UploaderComponent },
    {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
]
```

This helped to achieve route as:

```
http://localhost:4200/parent#/upload
```